# Program Continues To Ask For Input Despite Input Being Given One (Mars Rover Python)

Tags: python

In the program below you are to operate a mars rover. You must first input ready to start the rover. Then enter moveto and a set of coordinates, finally type, n,s,e,w to move the rover in the designated spot and return a print as shown below. However upon entering one of those four letter, the program does nothing it simply asks for another input, any ideas?

```
print ("************************************")
print ("Welcome to the Mars Rover Control HQ")
print ("Print \"ready\" as the first command when prompted")
print ("Print dig or moveto (with coordinates) afterwards")
print ("You can also print, n, s, e, or w, to move in those directions")
print ("************************************")

import random  # allows computer to grab random commands, for the objects to dig
x = 0  # this is the starting point of the rover
y = 0
print("The Mars Rover is currently at position", x, y)
TARDIS = "no"  # at orgin rover it at rest and cannot move(this variable will change if command is ready)otherwise loop does not work!
Mars = 1  # this acts like a while True, as long as Mars is 1 it will create an infinite loop
while Mars == 1:  # starts the program
    commandT = input("Please enter your command for the rover:")  # this asks for the a string for commandT
    space0 = int(commandT.find(" "))  # find the blanks spaces between direction and units
    lengthC = len(commandT)  # this will find the length of the command

    compass = commandT[0:space0]  # find first character to the space between direction and number

    commandT2 = commandT[7:lengthC]  # moveto takes up 7 characters and will count up to the total length of string
    space1 = int(commandT2.find(" "))  # this will find the blank space in the moveto command

    if commandT == "ready":   # this will ready rover
        print ("Rover is awake and ready for use")
        TARDIS = "ready"
    # else:
        # print"Please ready the rover!"  # must ready rover to continue into other loop, error message will show

    if TARDIS == ("ready"):
        if commandT == "dig":  # if command was dig, computer will randomly choose between the 5 choices
            objects = random.choice(['David Bowie Life On Mars Record', 'A Dalorean', 'A Hover Board', 'Star Man', 'Water'])
            print ("The rover found %s!" % objects)

        if commandT[0:6] == "moveto":   # if command is in moveto format
            x = (commandT2[0:space1])   # will convert orginal coordinates to values
            y = (commandT2[space1:lengthC])
            print("The Mars Rover has moved to position", x, y)

# this is for the compass directions if chosen......
        if compass[0:6] == "n":   # if chosen to move north
            value = int(commandT[space0:lengthC])
            y += value   # moves up positive y axis
            print("The Mars Rover has moved to position", x, y)
        if compass[0:6] == "s":   # if chosen to move south
            value = int(commandT[space0:lengthC])
            y -= value   # moves down negative y axis
            print("The Mars Rover has moved to position", x, y)
        if compass[0:6] == "e":   # if chosen to move east
            value = int(commandT[space0:lengthC])
            x += value   # moves up positive x axis
            print("The Mars Rover has moved to position", x, y)
        if compass[0:6] == "w":   # if chosen to move west
            movement = int(commandT[space0:lengthC])
            x -= movement   # moves down negative x axis
            print("The Mars Rover has moved to position", x, y)

        if commandT == "return":  # if command is return
            x = 0  # convert coordinates back to origin
            y = 0
            print("The Mars Rover has moved to position", x, y)
        if commandT == "rest":   # if command is rest
            Mars = 2   # stops the loop because Mars=1 is no longer true!
            print ("Rover is done for the day.")
    else:
        print("Error, cannot complete command")  # these error messages will show if rover is not ready
        print("Please ready the rover to continue")
```

Comment: Have you even tried to debug it?

Comment: yes I did, it did not return anything

Comment: TessellatingHeckler, got any suggestions on what I could do instead??

Comment: I would recommend using [the python debugger](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html) to inspect your code and see what the values for `commandT` and `compass` actually are, then compare them with what you expect them to be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of your if statements for the compass are not triggering because :

**compass[0:6] is not equal to "w" or "n" or any single char it is a single character being compared to 5 chars**

make everything just a string or make them all a list of the same size but you have to compare the same length list to the same length or compare a string to a string-not a :list[1]==list[5] # if you see what I mean

Comment: so would you replace if compass with the list part

Comment: 1) Change the "compass[0:6]" if statements to "compass[0]" and as you know be sure to add the number after as it is not user input proofed yet

Comment: It works for me as long as I enter the number after ,For instance e did not work and would just repeat then I changed it as I mentioned and it will only then work if a number is added with a space e.g "e 20"

Comment: so do you reckon adding a number right after entering the letter??

Comment: Yes , change the if to "compass[0] " then hit "e 20" then enter, it will trigger the if and the 20 will still be available in the if via the unrelated slice inside the if...it is working for me[Update just e one first to get the trouble shooting going]

Answer (score 0):

1) Change the introduction text that tells you how to use it, so it's correct:

```
print ("You can also print, n, s, e, or w, to move in those directions")
```

to

```
print ("You can also print, n 4, s 4, e 4, or w 4, to move 4 in those directions")
```

because I tripped up when I wasn't expecting it to need distances, and it does.

2) The lines `if compass[0:5] == "n"` are trying to compare a 5 character string with a 1 character string and see if they are the same. They will never be the same.

Change them to `if compass[0] == "n"` for the four directions, then commands like "n 4" will move 4 units north.

---

Unrelated to the question, but for fun I started to rewrite it to reduce code duplication and rename the variables. It ended up becoming object oriented; it's now split between a front end communications interface that takes commands and processes them a little bit for convenience, and a remote rover - hypothetically it could support multiple rovers now, if the command interface was upgraded.

The rover is on Mars, so it can't print directly to the screen it can only return text. The rover is the authority on what commands it can and can't accept, so the interface will send any command to it, and if it has a method named for the command you send, it runs it, otherwise it errors.

The command and parameter handling is reduced to single commands, or commands with one or two numbers as parameters, and should be more robust regarding errors because of it.

[Run it on repl.it here](https://repl.it/CPt1)

```
import random

objects = [ # Things it can dig up
    'David Bowie Life On Mars Record', 'A DeLorean', 
    'A Hover Board', 'Star Man', 'Water'
    ]

print ("************************************")
print ("Welcome to the Mars Rover Control HQ")
print ("Print 'ready' as the first command when prompted")
print ("Print dig or moveto (with coordinates) afterwards")
print ("You can also print, n, s, e, or w, to move in those directions")
print ("************************************")

class Rover:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x, self.y = 0, 0
        self.resting, self.available = True, True

    def ready(self):
        self.resting = False
        return "Rover is awake and ready for use"

    def dig(self):
        return "The rover found {}!".format(random.choice(objects))

    def moveto(self, x, y):
        self.x, self.y = x, y
        return "The Mars Rover is at position {}, {}".format(self.x, self.y)

    def rest(self):
        self.resting, self.available = True, False
        return "Rover is done for the day"

    def instruct(self, command, params):
        if self.resting and command != "ready":
            return "Error, cannot complete command\nPlease 'ready' the rover to continue"
        else:
            try:
                return getattr(self, command)(*params)
            except:
                return "Rover command error"

rover = Rover()
print("The Mars Rover is at position {}, {}".format(rover.x, rover.y))

while rover.available:
    command = input("Please enter your command for the rover:").split(' ')
    command, params = command[0], command[1:]

    if all(p.isdigit() for p in params):
        params = list(map(int, params))
    else:
        print("Command error: parameters X Y need to be numbers")
        continue

    if command == "return":
        command, params = "moveto", (0, 0)

    elif command in ("n", "e", "s", "w"):
        if not params: params = [1]
        distance = params[0]
        if command == "n": params = (rover.x, rover.y+distance)
        if command == "e": params = (rover.x+distance, rover.y)
        if command == "s": params = (rover.x, rover.y-distance)
        if command == "w": params = (rover.x-distance, rover.y)
        command = "moveto"

    print(rover.instruct(command, params))
```

Comment: The code is written to need a number along with the compass directions. You don't know that it needs a number, therefore ... you didn't write it?